# Differentiating the causes of InvalidAttributeValueException

Tags: java, ldap, jndi, spring-ldap

I'm trying to determine via `InvalidAttributeValueException` instance, what was the cause for the LDAP error code 19 (password policy error) so I will be able to display an informative error message in the UI.

The current LDAP service I'm using is openLDAP (as an embedded LDAP in the application) and it provides a pretty informative message that was good enough to display (i.e. `"[LDAP: error code 19 - Password fails quality checking policy]"` & `"[LDAP: error code 19 - Password is in history of old passwords]"`)

But now I want to support Active Directory & other LDAP providers (that will be external), and from what I've seen in rfc2251 and various other sources - every implementation puts it's own exception message and the only standard thing is the error code 19 mapping to `InvalidAttributeValueException`  and not to a specific issue.

Is there a solution (even a partial one) for differentiating between the different causes of an error code 19?
Is there a way, given an `InvalidAttributeValueException` instance, to query the LDAP for an answer to that question?

Thanks

Comment: Never seen such a method. The thing you found in RFC 2251 really answers your question.

Comment: I don't think that since 1997 no one found a solution to this problem.. There must be some standard way to query the LDAP via JNDI to see why the password change failed, showing a general message like "Password fails quality checking" after a password rejected due to being in the history list is evil and unusable.

Comment: If there was a 'general message' it would be specified in the RFC.

Comment: @EJP you didn't understand what I meant in the last part of my comment, but I got the gist. I've extended my knowledge on LDAP and I apparently the feature I wanted to implement is simply irrelevant.  Please post an answer so I can award you the bounty. Thanks.

Comment: Correct, I didn't understand it, because it doesn't make sense. If the password is in the history list you get some message that says so. If it fails quality checking, ditto. You don't get a 'quality checking' message in association with a history list problem.

Comment: What I meant is that for both scenarios I get the same message from the LDAP - I cant differentiate between them. That causes **me** to display to the user some general message "Something is wrong with your password" and when its an issue with the history list - its plain evil.. the user only knows he inserted a valid password but for some unknown reason the system wont accept it

Comment: but, as I said in my previous comment, this entire scenario is irrelevant - When the application is connected to an external LDAP, no one expects some minor application to manage the passwords in it, there are designated tools for that, thus in such situation, the entire some parts in my user management module are simply irrelevant.

Comment: That's clearer now, but nobody obliged you to display the password quality message that you are complaining about. It is indeed evil but as it was solely your idea what's your point exactly? Anyway see now my answer below.

Comment: Well, someone did obliged me, but that's irrelevant, I have my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comments above apply to the generic LDAP API, but I had forgotten something major. You need to investigate the request and response controls specified in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-behera-ldap-password-policy-10. This does work in OpenLDAP but I can't say whether it is supported by Active Directory. I have Java JNDI code that supports it which you are welcome to. The PasswordPolicyResponseControl can return the following:

```
/** Warning codes. */
public enum Warning
{
    /** Password expiration warning.*/
    timeBeforeExpiration,
    /** Grace logins warning.*/
    graceAuthNsRemaining,
    none;
}

/** Error codes. */
public enum Error
{
    /** The password has expired.*/
    passwordExpired,
    /**
     * The account has been locked, either by an administrator
     * or as a result of too many failed login attempts.
     */
    accountLocked,
    /**
     * The password has been reset by an administrator and must be changed immediately.
     */
    changeAfterReset,
    /**
     * The password policy does not permit the user to change his password.
     */
    passwordModNotAllowed,
    /**
     * The password policy requires the old password to be supplied
     * when changing passwords.
     * This indicates a programming error in the client.
     */
    mustSupplyOldPassword,
    /**
     * The new password has failed the quality check.
     */
    insufficientPasswordQuality,
    /**
     * The new password is too short.
     */
    passwordTooShort,
    /**
     * The current password is too new to change yet.
     */
    passwordTooYoung,
    /**
     * The password policy specifies keeping a password history
     * and the new password is already in it.
     */
    passwordInHistory,
    /**
     * Error parsing the response control.
     * This indicates a programming error either in this
     * class or in the LDAP server.
     */
    unparseableResponseControl,
    /**
     * No additional information.
     * This can be seen e.g. when the user simply logs
     * in with the wrong password.
     */
    none;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the [specs of the given exception](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.naming/javax/naming/directory/InvalidAttributeValueException.html) you can find out the following:

- The cause, which will vary by the implementation is given in the constructor variant

`InvalidAttributeValueException(String explanation)`

- it has a method to call it:

`exception.getExplanation()`

which gives the value put in with the constructor.

Because the constructor takes the value as a String, not an enum, it may be impossible to get a list of values each coder has put to this value when coding the different solutions. So, as you found out, everyone writes what they find appropriate: all things differently and thus write other things.

That's what I can say by the specs.

Comment: The exception documentation is clear. What I wanted is to see if anyone knows about a way to query the LDAP to see what cause said exception. but thanks anyway :)